# Linking a combobox and textbox through list index

Tags: combobox, textbox, vb6, listitem

I have a combobox and a textbox. The combobox is sorted as a list alphabetically and has five items. "APPLE" "BEAR" "CAT" "DOG" "ELK". In the database, they are listed with a weight so

APPLE Weighs 2, BEAR weighs 100, CAT weighs 7, DOG weighs 20 and ELK weighs 30,

I would like to change the combobox to select the right animal based off of the weight i type in on Lost_Focus. So i have

```
 For i = 0 To 4
    If txtField.Text = Me.cmbAnimal.ItemData(i) Then
        Me.cmbAnimal.ListIndex = i
    End If

    Next i
```

However, this is comparing the weight to the animal name. How can i reword this?

Comment: There is an associated TAG property as well, for each animal, put the weight in the TAG either during declaration, manual adding or loops and then compare the text with the tag of that item instead, that will give you what you want. Let me know if you need a working example, I will have to be on the system that has my VB6 copy.

Comment: Yes, i would like a working example that would help

Comment: Give me a little bit and I will get that off to you and post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sample you have 2 different comboboxes: `cmbAnimal` and `cmbSeqCarrier`. Which one are you using?

You have the right idea about using ItemData (assuming it stores the weight of the animal). In the sample below, `ItemData` property holds the weights. If `Text1` is the box where you enter the weight, the sample below should do the task you are asking.

```
'Load weights with the names to a combobox
Private Sub Form_Load()
    cmbAnimal.AddItem "APPLE"
    cmbAnimal.ItemData(cmbAnimal.NewIndex) = 2
    cmbAnimal.AddItem "BEAR "
    cmbAnimal.ItemData(cmbAnimal.NewIndex) = 100
    cmbAnimal.AddItem "CAT"
    cmbAnimal.ItemData(cmbAnimal.NewIndex) = 7
    cmbAnimal.AddItem "DOG"
    cmbAnimal.ItemData(cmbAnimal.NewIndex) = 20
    cmbAnimal.AddItem "ELK"
    cmbAnimal.ItemData(cmbAnimal.NewIndex) = 30
End Sub
```

If you have weights loaded into `ItemData`, then this will work just fine:

```
Private Sub Text1_LostFocus()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To cmbAnimal.ListCount - 1
        ' compare weight entered into text box with weights stored in the combobox
        If Trim(cmbAnimal.ItemData(i)) = Trim(Text1.Text) Then
            cmbAnimal.ListIndex = (i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: oops that should be animal, ill change it

Comment: So whats the problem? You enter weight and u get the animal. Is that not what you wanted? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: George, the assumption you made with the answer was false. Each animal has a weight in the database, but its not stored anywhere. Ive gotten it to where i just need to find the combo box index based off of the string so how could i find the index of "CAT"

Comment: I fail to see connection `i just need to find the combo box index based off of the string`. How do you connect the input string, which is the weight, to the combo index without having the weights loaded in the combobox? When you are populating combobox with names, can you populate `ItemData` with the weights?

Comment: +1 Thank you George, I got held up with flight delays and didn't get a chance to get back to this, thank you for handling the code sample.